# Using SQLDelight JVM Driver on Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sqldelight

Is it possible to use the SQLDelight JVM driver on a pure Java/Kotlin module which is later going to be consumed on an Android module?

Just wondering because I like the idea of having the persistency layer of my app on its Domain module, which happens to be a pure Kotlin module with no dependency to the Android framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my question had kind of an obvious answer :facepalm:

I ended up having my `.sq` files in my `Domain` module, and consuming the generated DAO in my `Data` module.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible, I can share you some links:
https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/jvm_sqlite/

try to use Gradle build system.